# Is there a discontinuous range class for Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to represent an arbitrarily complex range of real values, which can be discontinuous, i.e.:

```
0--4 and 5--6 and 7.12423--8
```

Where I'll be adding new ranges incrementally:

```
(0--4 and 5--6 and 7.12423--8) | ( 2--7) = (0--7 and 7.12423--8)
```

I don't really know the right language to describe this, so I'm struggling to search, but it seems like a class probably already exists to do what I want to do. Does it?

Comment: why not implement it yourself? it's not such a big deal.

Comment: @Gabi -- That's terrible advice. Never re-invent the wheel when you don't have to, unless it's a learning exercise, or the only wheel you can find is square. @Autopulated I think `numpy` has such a feature but I don't recall it right now.

Comment: @agf this still doesn't seem like a big deal to me

Comment: @agf --- I've noticed your stuff recently, and it's all right on target.  Including the above, +1.

Comment: Thanks. Programming is one of those things where everyone has their own definition of common sense; I'm glad ours overlap.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what values do you want when you iterate over the 7.12423--8 portion?

Comment: @Ethan Actually, my ranges are timestamps; further, they are indices (possibly extremely large) sets of discrete values -- so I'm actually using the ranges as something like pointers for where to start and stop iterating.

Comment: I actually have a related question: anything similar around that's specifically for integers? Ideally it should model +/- Infinity concepts as well. I have my own thing cooked up already but would love to have something more standardized.

Comment: @Karl, I ended up cooking my own on this too; the two libraries suggested by Ned weren't really up to the job.

Comment: @Karl: I was just looking at the source code for v1.0.0 of the [`interval`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0) module and it looks like it supports `Intervals` with boundaries of `+/-inf`.

Comment: @martineau Interesting; looks like I may have been beaten to it (publishing a robust implementation, I mean) while I was distracted by other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least a couple of packages listed in the Python Package Index which deal with intervals:

- [interval](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0)
- [pyinterval](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinterval/)

I've experimented with `interval` before and found it to be well-written and documented (at the moment its website seems to be unavailable).  I've not used `pyinterval`.

Comment: According to the description it supports __continuous__ ranges, not discontinuous ones.

Comment: Um, Interval supports discontinuous sets of continuous ranges.  Isn't that what it is in the OP's question?

Comment: Ack -- good point.  So now the question is can you iterate through an IntervalSet in Interval order;  somebody will have to read the docs! :)

Comment: @Ethan In fact I struggled to decide whether to use the word continuous or discontinuous in my question ;)

Comment: @Ethan: `interval.IntervalSets` in v1.0.0 of the [`interval`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0) module support iteration. Intervals are stored in order, starting with that with the left-most lower bound to that with the right-most.

Comment: Important : module "interval" is written for python 2, and will cause lots of pain to migrate to python 3.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the *interval* and *pyinterval* packages mentioned by Ned, there is also *pyinter*.

As *pyinterval* didn't compile on my machine, I only played with *interval* and *pyinter*.

The former seems better to me, because it has addition and subtraction operators defined for interval sets, which *pyinter* has not. Also when I tried to calculate the union of two discrete points, it worked as expected in *interval*, but raised AttributeError `("'int' object has no attribute 'overlaps'")` in *pyinter*.

One very visible difference of *pyinter* was the the `__repr__` function of the interval class which would output `(7,9]` instead of `Interval(7, 9, lower_closed=False, upper_closed=True)` (the latter is the representation of the *interval* package). While this is nice for quick interactive work, closed intervals might be confunded with two-element lists. Here I also like the *interval* package's approach more: It has a less ambiguous representation, but additionally defines a `__str__` method, so that when calling `str()` or `print()` on the example interval, it would output as `(7..9]`.